# Updating bios for Dell Inspiron 1525

Tags: bios, dell-inspiron

I would like to update my Dell Inspiron 1525 bios, but required utility provided from Dell 1525A_17.exe complains regading my battery is not charged. I can't charge my battery because of unknown reason it is not charging. How to force 1525A_17.exe do it's job and don't look at the battery?

Comment: You can't. Because MS have blocked BIOS updates without sufficient battery power to prevent you from bricking your laptop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I update bios without battery?](https://superuser.com/questions/879545/how-can-i-update-bios-without-battery)